# ASP.net MVC Datepicker with date validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, datepicker

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? I am trying to validate the date on a datepicker date to mm/dd/yyyy when allowing user input. I used validation code that was suggested to me, and have some other code in there to make sure the popup calendar goes away when they mouse down or press the tab key (if they don't put a date in at all).

```
   $(function () {
        $('.datepicker2').datepicker()
       .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
           $('.datepicker2').datepicker('hide');
       });
       ForceDatePickerFormat();
    });

    function ForceDatePickerFormat(dateValue) {
        $('.datepicker2').on('keydown', function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (keyCode == 9) {
                $('.datepicker2').datepicker('hide');
            }
        });
        $(".datepicker2").on("blur", function (e) {
               var selectedDate = dateValue;
               if(selectedDate == '')
               return false;

               var regExp = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/; //Declare Regex
               var dateArray = selectedDate.match(regExp); // is format OK?

               if (dateArray == null){
                 return false;
               }

               month = dateArray[1];
               day= dateArray[3];
               year = dateArray[5];        

               if (month < 1 || month > 12){
                  return false;
               }else if (day < 1 || day> 31){ 
                  return false;
               }else if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) && day ==31){
                  return false;
               }else if (month == 2){
               var isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
               if (day> 29 || (day ==29 && !isLeapYear)){
                  return false
               }
            }
           return true;
        });
    }
```

Comment: What datepicker plugin are you using? And why are you not just using client side validation?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap-datepicker.js. I'm pretty new to asp.net...I'm using DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy} in the model, but client wants to force the user to enter 4 digit year. What are other options? What specifically do you mean by client-side validation? I tried regex but could not find a string that worked. Also, client wanted drop-down calendar.  I welcome any help!

Comment: If the property your binding to is `DateTime` and you have enabled client side validation (included `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`) and included `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.yourDateProperty)` then all this is handled out of the box (you don't need any of this)

Comment: So, in the model, I currently have something like this: [DisplayName("Need Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Date not valid.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Need_Date { get; set; }
Do I keep this, and put the ValidateMessageFor in the View?

Comment: So, checked, and I do already have that set up. The problem is, it still allows the user to enter a 2-digit year. And, it makes the year 1915 by default. We have to force 4-digit year because user enters dates way in the future...it is not always 2000's. EVerything else IS handled by the client side validation.

Comment: You can just add a `RegularExpressionAttribute` to your model property

Comment: I could not find a regular expression that worked, that actually forced the 4-digit year. i looked through numerous libraries and posts, none of them worked. Here is one that I tried: [RegularExpression(@"^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$", ErrorMessage = "Date must be in format mm/dd/yyyy")]
Thank you immensely for your responses! Do you know of a regex that works to validate 4-digit year?

Comment: You already have one in the script :) - All it need to validate is that it ends in 4 digits after the date separator character. All the rest (validating that it is a valid date) will be taken care of by jquery validation.

Comment: I should clarify...I think the regex DOES validate mm/dd/yyyy, but if the user enters "1/1/15" in the date field, it treats it as valid and makes it "1915". It does not FORCE entry of the correct 4-digit year. So, I had to write code to force that at input. Is there a way to do that with client-side validation?

Comment: I just put the RegularExpression line back in, and typed 1/1/15 into the date field, and it was saved as "01/01/2015". Our customers add dates waaayyyyy into the future, so we have to specify the millenium.

Comment: But if you have `[RegularExpression(@"^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$")` you will get an validation error on the client. But is a use wants to add a date for `2115` then they are hardly going to enter just `15` anyway?

Comment: OMG...I just published the entire project and tried it again, and it worked!!! It validated after submitting, but I can still leave the check on the input. Thank you, thank you, thank you! Should I use the RegularExpression that you have above, or the one that I used? Yours looks better!

Comment: You have no idea how much you've helped me. This was in comments, so I don't think I can mark it accepted or vote up the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it validated perfectly while I was editing the field, but when I clicked submit to save the data, it gives me an error that the date is invalid, even if it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

follow the links:

http://formvalidation.io/examples/jquery-ui-datepicker/

```js
$(function() {

  $( "#jQueryValidateTest" ).validate();

  $( "[type=date]" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
      $( this ).valid();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.valid {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.error {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form id="jQueryValidateTest">
    <input type="date" required>
</form>​
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this, too. Sorry this question was marked "useless". I have really spent hours and hours researching. I'm just learning...I thought that's what this board was for.

Comment: does it matter if I use bootstrap datepicker or jquery ui datepicker? And, should I use the latest version?